# Accesing Python script for opencv from nodejs.

Tags: python, node.js, opencv

I tried calling my python script from Nodejs. The python script is opened successfully, however it does not allow me to access my webcam.

This is nodejs code where i called my python script.

```
app.post('/camera', (req, res) => {
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const ls = spawn('python', ['./HackRU2018/face_detect.py']);

    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });
})
```

Here is my python program.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml")
#numberofsamples = 0
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img_gray, 1.3, 5 )
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 3)
        roi_gray = img_gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color=img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        #numberofsamples=numberofsamples+1
         #   cv2.imwrite('user_images/'+"."+str(identification)+"."+str(numberofsamples)+".jpg", roi_gray)

        cv2.imshow('webcam', img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(33)
        if k ==27:
            break

       # elif numberofsamples>50:
        #    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It seems to work fine when i called python file separately. But does not work when i called it from nodejs.

Comment: Could you share how you call that Python script from Nodejs? And why would you want to do that?

Comment: const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const ls = spawn('python', ['./HackRU2018/face_detect.py']);
I called my python script using this. When clicking a button from web page, I want to run multiple files. The webcam seems to work for just a second, and the webcam light goes off.